# How to check if Edimax EW-7811Un driver has been correctly installed?

Tags: networking, wireless, driver, wireless-adapter

I am using an `Edimax EW-7811Un wireless adapter` on a `Raspberry Pi 2B` on which I have a `minibian` installed, a minimal image.
I think I've installed the `8192cu.ko` driver files correctly, but I'd like to know for sure, because there are issues with getting the wireless to connect to an eduroam network.

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Prints visible networks, so that already works. Is this already proof of a correctly installed wireless driver, or do I need to verify other things?

**EDIT#1**

Output of `lsmod | grep 8192`:

```
8192cu                528485  0
```

Output of `ip link`:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether b8:27:eb:3b:12:98 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlan0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether 74:da:38:54:72:b8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a driver is loaded, you can look at the output of `lsmod`.  This may (or may not) be a lengthy list and is not in lexicographical order, so filtering it through `grep` is useful.  Items in the list do not include the `.ko` suffix.

```
lsmod | grep 8192
```

Will show you if the module is loaded.  You won't see the column headers (to understand that, leave off `| grep ...`).

This doesn't necessarily mean it or the adapter are working.  For evidence of that, at least on the most fundamental level, you want to see if the kernel is reporting a wireless interface attached.

```
ip link
```

Will show you all available interfaces.  On Raspbian, if you only have one wifi adapter, you are looking for a `wlan0` interface.  There will normally be two others, `eth0` (ethernet) and `lo` (local loopback, a networking abstraction used by the system).

This does not necessarily mean everything is going to work well enough to establish a real wifi link, but it *probably* does.  Problems after this are usually do to misconfiguration.